# Connecting multiple TFMini sensors to Arduino uno

Tags: c++, arduino-uno, sensors

I need help getting each TFMini lidar sensor I have to measure distance, each sensor measure a different distance .  I havea total of three sensors .

In this code when I run it and open the serial monitor it doesn't measure any distance for me .It just print "" ALL distance in cm "" .

Thank you in advance here is the code.

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
#include<TFMini.h>
#include "Talkie.h"
#include "Vocab_US_Large.h"
#include "Vocab_Special.h"
#include "Vocab_US_TI99.h"
#include "TalkieUtils.h"

//Declaring variables and constants
TFMini TFFront;
TFMini TFRight;
TFMini TFLeft;
Talkie voice;                   //PIN 3 is by default the output for the speaker
SoftwareSerial SRight (4,5);    //(RX, TX)
SoftwareSerial SFront (6,7);    //(RX, TX)
SoftwareSerial SLeft (8,9);     //(RX, TX)

int TFBaudRate = 115200;
int USBBaudRate = 9600;
uint16_t threshold_distance = 100;       //Threshold distance in "cm"; speak only when any object is nearer than this distance

void setup() 
{
  //Initializing Baud Rates
  Serial.begin (USBBaudRate);
  while(!Serial);                     //Wait for USB Serial Port to connect
  Serial.println("Starting ......");
  SFront.begin (TFBaudRate);
  delay(50);
  SRight.begin (TFBaudRate);
  delay(50);
  SLeft.begin (TFBaudRate);
  delay(50);

  //Initializing TFMini Sensors
  TFFront.begin(&SFront);
  delay(100);
  TFRight.begin(&SRight);
  delay(100);
  TFLeft.begin(&SLeft);
  delay(100);  
}

void loop() 
{ 
  uint16_t Distances[3]={0,0,0};  //Initializing a blank array to store the distances of each side in each iteration
  Serial.println("All distances are in cm");

  //Getting and storing the distance from each side
  Distances[0] = TFFront.getDistance();
  Serial.print ("Front distance: ");
  Serial.println (Distances[0]);
  delay(50);
  Distances[1] = TFRight.getDistance();
  Serial.print ("Right distance: ");
  Serial.println (Distances[1]);
  delay(50);
  Distances[2] = TFLeft.getDistance();
  Serial.print ("Left distance: ");
  Serial.println (Distances[2]);
  delay(50);

  //Checking if another object is nearer than our set threshold and speaking
  if(Distances[0] < threshold_distance)    //Front Sensor
  {
    int dist_m0 = Distances[0]/100;
    voice.say(spt_SOME);
    voice.say(spt_THING);
    voice.say(spt_IN);
    voice.say(spt_FRONT);
    voice.say(sp2_AT);
    sayQFloat(&voice, dist_m0, 2, true, true);
    voice.say(sp2_METER);
    delay (100);
  }

  if(Distances[1] < threshold_distance)    //Right Sensor
  {
    int dist_m1 = Distances[1]/100;
    voice.say(spt_SOME);
    voice.say(spt_THING);
    voice.say(spt_ON);
    voice.say(spt_RIGHT);
    voice.say(sp2_AT);
    sayQFloat(&voice, dist_m1, 2, true, true);
    voice.say(sp2_METER);
    delay (100);
  }

  if(Distances[2] < threshold_distance)    //Left Sensor
  {
    int dist_m2 = Distances[2]/100;
    voice.say(spt_SOME);
    voice.say(spt_THING);
    voice.say(spt_ON);
    voice.say(spt_LEFT);
    voice.say(sp2_AT);
    sayQFloat(&voice, dist_m2, 2, true, true);
    voice.say(sp2_METER);
    delay (100);
  }  
}
```

Comment: `int TFBaudRate = 115200;` enable compiler warnings and read them.

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with Python and C?

Comment: 1-same nothing happen . 2-It doesn't have to do anything with Python and C!!

Comment: So why did you use those tags?

Comment: Arduino is an obsolete 8 bitter and `int` is 16 bits on such old systems. Therefore you can't store the value 115200 inside an `int`.

Comment: void setup() 
{
  //Initializing Baud Rates
  Serial.begin (115200);
  while(!Serial);                     //Wait for USB Serial Port to connect
  Serial.println("Starting ......");
  SFront.begin (115200);
  delay(50);
  SRight.begin (115200);
  delay(50);
  SLeft.begin (115200);
  delay(50);

Comment: Its still doesn't print the distances . it just print '' All distances in cm''

Comment: Like speaking to a wall... run [this](https://godbolt.org/z/x8ceev), then pick up the pieces from there.

Comment: did you just said like speaking to a wall ? what do you mean ?